# Modify Code - Convert an onEdit to Custom Menu to run - Google Apps Script / Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to convert the below code from onEdit to run with custom menu. So if criteria met when I press my custom script inside menu - it will run the code.

```
 function UpdateInventory(e){   
 var sh=e.range.getSheet();
       if(sh.getName()!='InComing Donations')return
       if(e.range.columnStart==11 && e.value=="TRUE") {
 var tsh=e.source.getSheetByName("RECTOONLINE");
 var trg=tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,1);
 sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,8).copyTo(trg);           
 }}
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function UpdateInventory(){  
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('InComing Donations');
  var rg=sh.getActiveRange();
  var r=rg.getRow();
  var c=rg.getColumn();
  var v=sh.getRange(r,c).getValue();
  if(c==17 && v=='TRUE') {
    var tsh=e.source.getSheetByName("RECTOONLINE");
    var trg=tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,1);
    sh.getRange(r,1,1,8).copyTo(trg);           
  }
}
```